# Magento 2 : How to Override Admin Template File

Tags: magento2, admin, overrides

I'm developing a custom module in magento 2. 
I need to change the file located in `Magento/Sales/view/Adminhtml/Templates/Items/Column/name.phtml`.

How can I override file in custom extension?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try following way:

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="column_name">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/items/column/name.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy original file into following location:

```
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/items/column/name.phtml
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Beware that using action tag is no longer recommended, you should use `<referenceBlock name="column_name" template="Vendor_Module::order/items/column/name.phtml"/>`

Comment: Don't worry, look here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3356

Comment: What if the file does not have a layout and it is set in code. Like `magento/module-payment/view/adminhtml/templates/info/substitution.phtml`

Comment: @StevieG you can overwrite any template by replacing your own theme, or overwrite Block class and set $_template variable or this answer.